# Can ADAL be used with AD FS instead of Azure AD?

Tags: android, active-directory, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-msal

I've successfully used the [ADAL library for Android](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android) to sign in with Azure AD. I'd need to connect to an AD FS instead of Azure AD. The AD FS is not cloud-federated.

I have found this example for ADAL.js that apparently shows how to authenticate against AD FS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/single-page-application-with-ad-fs

1. Can the Android version connect to AD FS as well, or is it only possible in the JavaScript version of ADAL?
2. If it were possible, how to register the app and what to put in the `auth_config.json` file? (Any example will be much appreciated)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, ADAL can be used with ADFS. You need to register the app in ADFS using the Application Group folder of the management console. E.g.: [overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/enabling-oauth-confidential-clients-with-ad-fs) or [ADFS setup details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/enabling-oauth-confidential-clients-with-ad-fs).

Comment: All those steps are meant for the AD admin. I'm just a client-side developer. What I need is to configure the library in the client side. In ADAL for Android it is done using a JSON file. I've to provide several fields, for instance, `client_id`, `redirect_uri` (which I assume it can be an arbitrary string for native) and `authorities`. This last field is the most complex, it contains `type`, `audience` and inside it, `type` and `tenant_id`. I've no idea how to fill in those fields, and I have to request that info from the AD guys. Is there an example for Android anywhere?

Comment: [Alternate details on setting up an ADFS application group](https://aadguide.azurewebsites.net/adfs2016/appgroups/). You will need an administrator on the server to do this. This analogous to creating an app registration in AAD.

Comment: The only different between AAD and AD FS should be the ```MetadataEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AdfsMetadataEndpoint"]```. This value will be something along the lines of ```https://sts.mycompany.com/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration```.

Comment: @MisterSmith Could you able to achieve the ADFS with ADAL. From an Android standpoint, what are all the things we need to perform for successfully authenticating? If possible can u share some code snippets?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using ADAL or MSAL? The auth_config.json file is only relevant for MSAL. ADAL can authenticate against AD FS directly through registering the app as a 'Native Application' in the AD FS >  Application Groups folder. You must have an administrator account or sufficient privileges to make this registration. Conceptually, this is similar to the JS docs you linked, however instead of using the [Implicit Grant Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) it uses the [Authorization Code Grant Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code). Unfortunately there is not explicit documentation on this for Android yet. If your AD FS environment is cloud federated, you can follow the [docs to use MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-android#step-2-register-your-application).

Comment: I'm using MSAL, which is the newer v2 version of ADAL (v1). I didn't know which one to use so I went for the most recent version. The AD FS I need to connect to is not cloud federated. Should I use the v1? Apparently the v2 is OK for both work and personal accounts, while v1 is only meant for work accounts.

Comment: It is recommended to use MSAL because it's the most up to date and supported, also you are correct that v2 provides one endpoint for various types of accounts. However at the moment to use MSAL with AD FS you must be cloud federated. ADAL can be connected with AD FS through the portal with the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Older is better. OK that answers question #1. As for #2, I've read the [official github sample in ADAL](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-android), and they are using ADAL v1.14. There is ADAL v2 alpha with a completely different API for `AuthenticationContext.acquireToken` that looks more like MSAL. Which version should I use? How would you configure the AD FS URL? Is it the authority parameter the one I need to override?

Comment: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/802